# Dropwizard spring data couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, dropwizard, odm, spring-data-couchbase

I am building a project with Dropwizard, Couchbase and ElasticSearch.

I am looking for a persistence layer like an ODM for Dropwizard and CouchBase. I looked over and found Spring-data-couchbase. Can I integrate DropWizard with Spring-data-couchbase and just use Spring-data-couchbase just for persistence? If I just use Spring-data-couchbase will it create an IOC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for an ODM layer, we recently added a light one to the Java SDK, see Entity Mapping: http://blog.couchbase.com/javasdk-2.2-dp

Also if you are looking to use Spring Data Couchbase, you should maybe look into Spring boot, that basically does the same things as DropWizard.  But of course Spring Data Couchbase is more integrated with Spring Boot than DropWizard.

As for DropWizard and Spring, yes I guess you would drag some Spring dependency in there so it might create some stuff that already have an equivalent in Dropwizard. But I have no knowledge of Dropwizard so, not sure.